# Готовая библиотека регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Существует вообще какая-нибудь готовая библиотека регулярных выражений на C++? Или только на C# есть нормальное что-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть. И не одна.

- для начала классика - [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).
- в с++ в tr1 есть [cpp_regex](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html), а в самый последних компиляторах вообще в std::regex
- в хорошей библиотеке [poco](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.RegularExpression.html)
- ну и никто не запрещает использовать [pcre](http://www.pcre.org/).

Comment: оО, неплохо) спс , +1